# How to show graphQl api run on frontend page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

How to show graphQl api run on frontend page in magento2 ?

I have created custom product collection api so i need to need to display that api collection show on phtml page.

Comment: Can you please add some more details in your question. As from the question it is not clear what answer you are expecting.

Comment: Any update on this question?